# Android connecting to local java ServerSocket?

Tags: android, networking

I have written a basic java http server using sockets. It has simple REST interface and responds to GET/POST requests. I set out to do a small android app connecting to this interface. I can connect to my servers using browsers from my pc and also I tried out from vmware player virtual machines ubuntu and xp. All work well. I was afraid of testing on emulator so deployed the app on android phone. It cannot connect to the java servers. Both device and PC is connected to same network. Am I missing something here like port forwarding etc ? If that's the problem how come I was able to connect from my virtual machines?

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 1):

Can you have forgotten to set the internet permission perhaps?
You need this in your android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

/Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Can you connect to this server from another PC running on the same network?  (This is not the same as connecting from a virtual machine running on the same box as the server)

If not, you may have a firewall issue on the PC.

You should test on the android emulator too, use the alias for the host loopback interface address that you can find in the emulator docs.

Comment: I have to try this out properly.. will checkout the emulator stuff. thanks.

Comment: Ah just came to my lab and tried it out. I always thought that when my laptop is in lab connected to lab wifi I assumed that it will behave like any other pc in the network. If I run the GET requests from my laptop to a server on any of the lab machine it works.. even android is able to send the GET request through socket programming. Tried to use apache HTTPClient but it does not accept IPaddresses which is weird.. I will look into it. Thanks for your suggestions.